# Developer Portal Error

Tags: ios, iphone

I tried to run one of my apps on my iPhone. When i click the run button, it shows a error saying **failed to code sign in** and when i click fix issue it goes through the fixing stuff and then says you can't run your app on a device.There is two errors saying saying `No provisioning profiles found: No non–expired provisioning profiles were found` and `code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.4'`. Trying to fix the first error i tried to go to the developer portal to check but to whichever page i visit i am getting this error dialog. It says **An unspecified error occurred.**
You cannot run your app on a device. How would i fix this. My iPhone is iOS 8.4 and my Xcode is version 6.4. I also have the iOS developer program

Comment: Have you tried adding your account to Xcode->Preferences->Account

Comment: At the start i already did it